Set of columns with struct fields or vectors
I'm coding a simple single player card game called poker squares as my first project in Rust. I want to create a board with five columns that store five cards each. To do that, I've got two approaches that include using vectors and struct fields respectively but I struggle implementing either of them. See details for each above:
Card.rs
fetches cards from deckofcards API
struct Card{
    value: String,
    suit: String
}

Struct fields
struct Board{
    one: Vec<Card>
    two: Vec<Card>
    three: Vec<Card>
    four: Vec<Card>
    five: Vec<Card>
}

I like this approach because it lets me access its fields easily and I think I can read it with ease. However, I know that there's no a native way to iterate over struct fields in Rust so I have to pass a function five times in five lines of code to evaluate each column hand and I doubt that's an efficient solution
Vector
struct Board {
    fields: Vec<Vec<Card>>
}

I like to rely on built-in vectors functions such as map to run evaluate hands for each column. However, this solution isn't very readable and it can be a bit confusing for me as a beginner to know how I'm getting results for each column. What's important here is that I'm not trying to make a matrix this time because columns are not interrelated (approach one earns another point in that respect)
What's my best option? I'm aware this isn't a one solution question we all expect on Stack Overflow but again, I'm a beginner and I struggle to find out what's best in this case.
Can anyone share some light on this please?

This is opinion-based, but I suggest an array: struct Board{ columns: [Vec<Card>; 5] }

Hi @FinnBear! Yeah I'm aware this is opinion-based but I'm an absolute beginner and I couldn't make my mind about this. Thanks for you suggestion.
